# Append new child item to specific node

Tags: xml, powershell

How do I updates an XML file with PowerShell previously selecting the right node?

I've tried so far:

```bsh
$PATH = ".\file.xml"
$XML = [xml](Get-Content -path $PATH)

$NSMGR = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($XML.NameTable)
$NSMGR.AddNamespace("ns", $XML.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI)

$XML.selectSingleNode("//ns:component[@name='Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup']", $NSMGR)

$NEWCHILD = $XML.CreateElement("TESTELEMENT")
$NEWCHILD.set_innerXML("TESTTEXT")

$XML.save(".\file.xml")
```

I want to add a child item to the node `<component>`. There is more than one `<component>` node, so I need to preselect the right one by the name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have the code to select the intended parent node and create the new child node. You just need to append the new child to the parent.

```bsh
$parent = $XML.selectSingleNode("//ns:component[@name='Microsoft-Windows-Shell-Setup']", $NSMGR)

$NEWCHILD = $XML.CreateElement("TESTELEMENT")
$NEWCHILD.set_innerXML("TESTTEXT")
$parent.AppendChild($NEWCHILD)
```